# What is the UnmanagedMemoryStream for?

Tags: c#, io, unsafe

Can someone tell me what the `UnmanagedMemoryStream` class is used for?

I am not able to figure out how and when this class could be useful?

Answer (score 11):

Using the UnmanagedMemoryStream allows you to read an unmanaged stream without copying everything into the managed heap first, therefore it's less memory intensive when dealing with unmanaged streams.  This also allows you to get around memory limitations if you are dealing with a lot of data.

Edit:  Note that there is a 2GB limitation with MemoryStream, so you have to use the UnmanagedMemoryStream if you exceed this limitation.

Comment: Hi, I had read the article that you have mentioned above. It's just that I wanted to know if thisis the indeed the real benefit. Thanks a lot for your comments :)

Answer (score 5):

`UnmanagedMemoryStream` allows you to access memory that has not been allocated by the Common Language Runtime, which is useful mainly if you want to acess memory allocated by unmanaged code through the `Stream` interface (e.g. because you already have code that operates on streams).

Of course there's nothing keeping you from allocating unmanaged memory from within C# through the [`Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) class and wrapping that in an `UnmanagedMemoryStream`, but that's just making life more difficult since you could have used `MemoryStream` instead and it's really, really unlikely that assuming manual control of the memory that backs the stream is going to offer any benefit.